# How to prove statement: If A, then if B, then C.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, soft-question, formal-proofs

I was wondering. In general, what are the approaches to proving nested if statements when doing a direct proof?
Thanks.

Comment: The statement $A\Rightarrow(B\Rightarrow C)$ is equivalent to $(A\land B)\Rightarrow C$. That’s usually easier to wrap your head around.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: if you're satisfied with you're answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "nested if statements", In general:

\begin{align}
P_1\to(P_2\to\dots (P_{n-1}\to(P_n\to Q))))
&\Leftrightarrow (P_1\land P_2\land \dots \land P_{n-1}\land P_n)\to Q\tag*{$(1)$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \neg P_1\lor\neg P_2\lor \dots \lor\neg P_{n-1}\lor\neg P_n\lor Q\tag*{$(2)$}\\
&\not\Leftrightarrow P_1\land P_2\land \dots \land P_{n-1}\land P_n\land\neg Q\tag*{$(3)$}\\
\end{align}

For $(1)$ it's a direct proof, basicly assume $P_1\dots P_n$, then prove $Q$ is a logical consequence of them.
$(2)$ can also be written as:
$$\neg Q\to(\neg P_1\lor\neg P_2\lor \dots \lor\neg P_{n-1}\lor\neg P_n)$$

In this case, assume $\neg Q$, if this implies any one in $\neg P_1\dots\neg P_n$ hold, it proves the statements.

Sometimes if it's hard to construct a direct proof, $(3)$ would also be a good choice, which is the negation of $(1)$, first assume that $P_1\dots P_n$, and $\neg Q$. If you can prove it's false, then that implies $(1)$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the 'inside' conditional is the consequent of the 'outside' conditional, you can do a conditional proof inside a conditional proof. Formally, it would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a \rightarrow (b \rightarrow c) \Leftrightarrow (a \wedge b) \rightarrow c$ by the exportation law. The following are common ways to prove such a statement:

**Direct Proof**

Assume $a$ and $b$, and then derive $c$.

**Proof by Contrapositive**

Prove the contrapositive of $(a \wedge b) \rightarrow c$, which is $\neg c \rightarrow \neg(a \wedge b) \Leftrightarrow \neg c \rightarrow (\neg a \vee \neg b)$. You can do this by assuming $\neg c$ and then deriving $\neg a \vee \neg b$.

**Proof by Contradiction**

Assume the negation of $(a \wedge b) \rightarrow c$, which is $a \wedge b \wedge \neg c$, and then derive a contradiction.